# Windowsの仮想マシンのネットワークをVirtIO化したい

Tags: linux

virtioネットワーク デバイスを Windowsで認識させるには、
以下の記事の[7]のように、デバイスマネージャからドライバを読み込ませる必要があると思います。

[KVM - Windows のネットワークデバイスをVirtIO化する](https://www.server-world.info/query?os=CentOS_6&p=x_kvm&f=5)

上記の手順をGUIでなくコマンドで行う方法はないでしょうか？

WindowsVMはvirt-installコマンドで実施しているのですが、 `--network bridge=br0,model=virtio` のように指定しただけではVMが起動しないので困っています。

Comment: ゲスト OS がどのドライバーを使用するかは, ゲスト OS側で(何らかの)操作しないとムリだと思いますが

Comment: やはりそうですよね。ありがとうございます。